# How to add a class to ONE of the divs in a foreach loop

Tags: php, class, loops, foreach

So I crated a class such as:

```
class CoreTheme_Form_Helpers_TabbedForm extends AisisCore_Form_Helpers_Content{

    protected $_html = '';

    public function init(){
        parent::init();

        if(isset($this->_options)){
            $this->_html .= '<ul class="nav nav-tabs">';
            foreach($this->_options as $options){
              $this->_html .= '<li><a href="#'.str_replace(" ", "", $options['tab']).'" data-toggle="tab">
                '.$options['tab'].'</a></li>';
            }
            $this->_html .= '</ul>';

            $this->_html .= '<div class="tab-content">';
            foreach($this->_options as $options){
                $this->_html .= '<div class="tab-pane" id="'.str_replace(" ", "", $options['tab']).'">...</div>';
            }
            $this->_html .= '</div>';           
        }
    }

    public function __toString(){
        return $this->_html;
    }
}
```

What I am looking to do is add the class active to the div with the class tab-pane, but only once, and only to the first one.

so in:

```
foreach($this->_options as $options){
    $this->_html .= '<div class="tab-pane" id="'.str_replace(" ", "", $options['tab']).'">...</div>';
}
```

the html should be something like:

```
<div class="tab-pane active" id="something">...</div>
<div class="tab-pane" id="something1">...</div>
<div class="tab-pane" id="something2">...</div>
```

ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$active = " active";
foreach($this->_options as $options){

    $this->_html .= '<div class="tab-pane'. $active .'" id="'.str_replace(" ", "", $options['tab']).'">...</div>';
    $active = "";

}
```

I think it can works

Answer (score 1):

Just use a variable to store the extra class `active` and reset it after the first set.

```
$extraClass = "active";
foreach($this->_options as $options){
    $this->_html .= '<div class="tab-pane '.$extraClass. '" id="'.str_replace(" ", "", $options['tab']).'">...</div>';
    $extraClass = "";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a jQuery one-liner if you don't mind adding it from the client:

```
$('.tab-pane').first().addClass('active');
```

Comment: I like this because it takes the concern where it belongs: In the view/display.

Answer (score 0):

If you need a counter, why use `foreach`? Use a regular `for`:

```
for ($i=0 ; $i < count($this->_options) ; $i++){

    $options = $this->_options[$i];

    if ($i==0) {
        // do something else
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do a str_replace to replace the whole for:

```
str_replace('tab-pane', 'tab-pane active', $this->_html, 1);
```

... where the last parameter, being 1, is the amount of times you replace it.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php